# Javascript listener for objects with unknown ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

In a view, I iterate through a collection and fill out various sets of information for each one. For each value in this collection there is a dropdown menu, which I want to have fill in a specific div based on the choice.

```
<% @model.samples.each do |sample| %>
  <div class="top">
    <%=fields_for 'asample[]', sample, do |a_form| %>
      Dropdown: <%=a_form.select..........{id: "ex#{sample.id}"} %>
  </div>
  <div id="hold_partial>
      <%= render partial: "/folder/dropdown_based_partial" %>
```

I understand how to do this regularly, I'm just not sure how to get a unique listener for each possible sample in samples.  A suggestion was an abstract js class but I'm not 100% confident how that would work.  Any suggestions?  I can elaborate further if this is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the first problem you're going to run into is that you're going to have multiple `div`s with `id="hold_partial"`. (BTW, you have a missing `"` at the end of `"hold_partial`.

Now, you could do something like:

```
<% @model.samples.each do |sample| %>
  <div class="top">
    <%=fields_for 'asample[]', sample, do |a_form| %>
      Dropdown: <%=a_form.select..........{id: "ex#{sample.id}", 'data-sample-id': sample.id} %>
  </div>
  <div id="hold-partial-#{sample.id}">
      <%= render partial: "/folder/dropdown_based_partial" %>
```

So that your `option` has `data-sample-id` and you have `div`s with unique `id`s that you can target based on your `options.data(sampleId)`.

Then, you can target the `.on 'change'` event something like:

```
$('select').on('change', function (e) {
  var targetPartial = $("#hold-partial-" + e.currentTarget.data('sampleId'));
  // do some fantastic stuff with your targeted partial
})
```

A couple of things:

- My tendency would be to add a class to your selects so that you're catching events from the desired selects (in case you have a bunch on your page that you want different behavior for).
- `e.currentTarget` will give you the element that generated the `change` event. From there, `.data('sampleId')` will give you the `id` you assigned in your loop.

HTH.

Comment: Thank you for the correction.  I was attempting to give a more generic example for what I have and I left that out, my apologies.  So I'm not the most fluent in rails or javascript...adding the 'data-sample-id' gives me the correct id to call for the div for the partial when any option is selected.  I'm still not completely following how I'd create a listener for a change on the possible x amount of these?

Comment: Are you using JQuery? Or plain JS?

Comment: JQuery.  "Extra text to hit the limit..."

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks, I think that'll do it.  My mind was stuck thinking that I needed to do a $('#this_specific_select').change verses doing it as you did above, or for a certain class of selects.

Comment: Please answer questions in the language that it is asked for.

Comment: Please clarify your comment. The OP stated they are using JQuery. The provided solution utilizes JQuery. The provided solution is written using coffeescript. The use (or not use) of coffescript was not specified and so it was clarified that the provided answer was written using coffeescript and it was advised that the OP would need to translate to regular JS if that is what they are using.

Comment: The question was tagged JavaScript. Answering with a solution in a completely different language that is not germane to the question is nothing more than a roadblock to understanding the answer. (And insulting the asker's choice of language is rude and unhelpful).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Have a nice day.